# R Alternative to nested for loop to create a list of URLs (expand.grid)

Tags: r, list, for-loop, nested, paste

I am trying to generate a list of URL combining the two following lists:

```
County<-list("ADAMS", "ALLEGHENY", "ARMSTRONG", "BEAVER", "BEDFORD", "BERKS", "BLAIR", "BRADFORD", "BUCKS", "BUTLER", "CAMBRIA", "CAMERON", "CARBON", "CENTRE", "CHESTER", "CLARION", "CLEARFIELD", "CLINTON", "COLUMBIA", "CRAWFORD", "CUMBERLAND", "DAUPHIN", "DELAWARE", "ELK", "ERIE", "FAYETTE", "FOREST", "FRANKLIN", "FULTON", "GREENE", "HUNTINGDON", "INDIANA", "JEFFERSON", "JUNIATA", "LACKAWANNA", "LANCASTER", "LAWRENCE", "LEBANON", "LEHIGH", "LUZERNE", "LYCOMING", "MCKEAN", "MERCER", "MIFFLIN", "MONROE", "MONTGOMERY", "MONTOUR", "NORTHAMPTON", "NORTHUMBERLAND", "PERRY", "PHILADELPHIA", "PIKE", "POTTER", "SCHUYLKILL", "SNYDER", "SOMERSET", "STATE LEVEL SITES", "SULLIVAN", "SUSQUEHANNA", "TIOGA", "UNION", "VENANGO", "WARREN", "WASHINGTON", "WAYNE", "WESTMORELAND", "WYOMING", "YORK")

RepPeriod<-list ("15AUGU","15JULU","15JUNU","15MAYU","15APRU", "15MARU", "15FEBU", "15JANU", "2015-1", "2014-2","2014-1","2014-0", "2013-2","2013-1","2013-0", "2012-2","2012-1","2012-0","2011-2","2011-1","2011-0", "2010-3","2010-2","2010-0", "2009-0","2008-0","2007-0", "2006-0","2005-0","2004-0","2003-0","2002-0","2001-0","2000-0")
```

In total it will be a list of 2312 elements (68 COUNTIES* 34 REPORTING PERIODS)

I have tried this:

```
URLlist<-as.character(c(1:2312))


for (a in 1:2312){
        for (i in 1:length(RepPeriod)){
                for (j in 1:length(County)){
         URLlist[a]<-paste0("https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/Production/ProductionByCountyExport.aspx?UNCONVENTIONAL_ONLY=false&INC_HOME_USE_WELLS=true&INC_NON_PRODUCING_WELLS=true&PERIOD=",RepPeriod[i],"&COUNTY=",County[j])
                }
        }
}
```

And it is just pasting the last reporting period and county 2312 times, instead of generating permutations:

```
URLlist[1:3]
[1] "https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/Production/ProductionByCountyExport.aspx?UNCONVENTIONAL_ONLY=false&INC_HOME_USE_WELLS=true&INC_NON_PRODUCING_WELLS=true&PERIOD=2000-0&COUNTY=YORK"
[2] "https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/Production/ProductionByCountyExport.aspx?UNCONVENTIONAL_ONLY=false&INC_HOME_USE_WELLS=true&INC_NON_PRODUCING_WELLS=true&PERIOD=2000-0&COUNTY=YORK"
[3] "https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/Production/ProductionByCountyExport.aspx?UNCONVENTIONAL_ONLY=false&INC_HOME_USE_WELLS=true&INC_NON_PRODUCING_WELLS=true&PERIOD=2000-0&COUNTY=YORK"
```

Can anybody help me see what I am doing wrong? Links to useful posts would help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eliminate loops using `expand.grid`, which expands all combinations of two vectors:

```
z <- expand.grid(RepPeriod, County)

URLlist <- paste0("https://www.paoilandgasreporting.state.pa.us/publicreports/Modules/Production/ProductionByCountyExport.aspx?UNCONVENTIONAL_ONLY=false&INC_HOME_USE_WELLS=true&INC_NON_PRODUCING_WELLS=true&PERIOD=",z$Var1,"&COUNTY=",z$Var2)
```

Comment: Clean and easy! Thanks!

For the sake of learning. Could you explain me why the loop was not working?

Answer (score 3):

The loop was not working because each element of the iteration of the first loop URLlist[a] is overwritten 68*34 times and at the end of each time only the last combination, i.e York a and and 2000-0 is stored. You have to have an incremental counter in the middle of the loop to avoid this such as this loop:

```
{k = 0
for (i in 1:length(RepPeriod)){
for (j in 1:length(County)){
  URLlist[j+k]<-paste0("........",RepPeriod[i],"&COUNTY=",County[j])
}
k = k + 68
}}
```

Comment: I see. Not as easy as I  thought. Thanks!